# It says pip is installed in my laptop, but it cannot download other modules

Tags: python, pip

I have tried lots of different modules to download on CMD, they seems to be installed at first(it shows until the downloading bar), but keep fails with whole lots of red errors. And I have reinstalled python few times, and had checked the proper ones pip to be work.(don't care "강상훈" that's just my Korean name)
Below, just an example of the errors

```
C:\Users\강상훈>pip install pyinstaller
Collecting pyinstaller
  Using cached pyinstaller-4.0.tar.gz (3.5 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\강상훈\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe' 'c:\users\강상훈\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\강상훈\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpqq61x1ww'
         cwd: C:\Users\강상훈\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o6lufvmx\pyinstaller
    Complete output (38 lines):
    running dist_info
    creating C:\Users\강상훈\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-ol2zzjvm\pyinstaller.egg-info
    writing C:\Users\강상훈\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-ol2zzjvm\pyinstaller.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to C:\Users\강상훈\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-ol2zzjvm\pyinstaller.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    writing entry points to C:\Users\강상훈\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-ol2zzjvm\pyinstaller.egg-info\entry_points.txt
    writing requirements to C:\Users\강상훈\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-ol2zzjvm\pyinstaller.egg-info\requires.txt
    writing top-level names to C:\Users\강상훈\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-ol2zzjvm\pyinstaller.egg-info\top_level.txt
    writing manifest file 'C:\Users\강상훈\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-ol2zzjvm\pyinstaller.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest file 'C:\Users\강상훈\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-ol2zzjvm\pyinstaller.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    Error in sitecustomize; set PYTHONVERBOSE for traceback:
    SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb0 in position 0: invalid start byte (sitecustomize.py, line 7)
    warning: no files found matching 'pyinstaller-gui.py'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\build'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\.waf-*'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\.waf3-*'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\waf-*'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\waf3-*'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\_sdks'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\.vagrant'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'bootloader\.lock-waf*'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'doc\source'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'doc\_build'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.tmp' found under directory 'doc'
    warning: no files found matching 'news\_template.rst'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'news'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'old'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'scripts'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'tests\scripts'
    no previously-included directories found matching '.github'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.*'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '*.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '*~'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.directory'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.py[co]' found anywhere in distribution
    writing manifest file 'C:\Users\강상훈\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-ol2zzjvm\pyinstaller.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    creating 'C:\Users\강상훈\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-ol2zzjvm\pyinstaller.dist-info'
    error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\강상훈\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe' 'c:\users\강상훈\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\강상훈\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpqq61x1ww' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Could please format your error code properly so we can read it ? Thank you.

Comment: You need to install `wheel`: `pip install wheel`

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, if you have wheel already, try reinstalling it, it will help. Also make sure you have [pywin32](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/releases) installed.

```
pip uninstall wheel
pip install wheel
pip install pyinstaller
```

Comment: @cbo I added the code now. I thought it was obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing

`pip install wheel`

And then

`pip install pyinstaller`

Comment: You don't need to run `python setup.py bdist_wheel`. Where would `setup.py` come from, anyway?

Comment: @jakub yeah it was a mistake